# How can I get current user in Flutter with Provider, Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-provider

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:signal_clone/models/user_model.dart';

class AuthService{
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? user) {
    if(user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(user.uid, user.email, user.displayName);
  }

  Stream<User?>? get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
  
}
```

To find out who the logged in user is, I wrote the code as follows.
I want to use user.uid, user.email, user.displayname in other widgets.

```
Consumer<AuthService>(
                builder: (context, value, child) =>
                    Container(child: Text(value.toString())),
              ),
```

I tried this, but I couldn't find the value. How can I get the value I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User?>(
      initialData: new User("id", "example@email.com", "example"),
      create: (BuildContext context) =>  AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Home Page',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Use `StreamProvider` of type `User`, the `StreamProvider` will listen to a stream and exposes its content to child and descendants. Then to consume it you can do:

```
Consumer<User>(builder: (context, userModel, _) {
   return Text('${userModel.email}');
   }),
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current user in firebase:

`User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`

I personally, I do not use provider or anything, I just call the above function
wherever I need it (or store in Provider and reload whenever new user logs in). e.g

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
return Container(child: Text(user.email)
```

Remember:
`import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';`